# Find files recursively and use them

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am looking for a script, that compares same files from two different paths.

1. Script has to accept 2 paths ie, oldfiles and newfiles directory path as arguments
2. Read first sub-folder name from oldfiles and search the same sub-folder name in newfiles path. If same sub folder found, then
3. Check, if both filename matches(not extension!), if so, then
4. Do something with this two files

Please help me!
He is the my script so far

```sh
# Process each file in directory_1, comparing it to directory_2
find $1/ -type f -name '*.txt' -print | while read src
do
    for filename in */*.txt; do
        echo $filename
        fn=$(basename "$filename")
        if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
            echo $filename
            newname=`echo $2/$fn|sed 's/\.txt$//g'`
            echo $newname
            #do something here with this two files
            echo "Done"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: You can use `$(basename "$filename" .txt)` to get the filename and remove the suffix at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `for filename` loop, `find` is printing the filenames.

Using `basename` is wrong, because it loses all the intermediate directories in the path. So use bash variable substitution to replace `$1` with `$2` in the path.

```
find "$1" -type f -name '*.txt' -print | while read filename
do
    echo "$filename"
    newname=${filename/$1/$2} # Replace old directory prefix with new prefix
    newname=${newname%.txt} # Remove extension
    echo "$newname"
    if [ -f "$newname" ]
    then
        #do something here with this two files
    fi
    echo "Done"
done
```

Comment: also:it it ok if i have "two //" ? /Users/test/Desktop/test2/folder1/test//file1.txt /Users/test/Desktop/test2/folder2/test//file1

Comment: You left out the space after `[`.

Comment: You don't need the `/` in the `find` command, that's what's doubling the slash. It's OK, but not needed.